# How to fix: Type Error when moving column in Associative List

Tags: if-statement, ocaml, typeerror

I am trying to move a column in an associative list and have code that upon my inspections appears to be valid.

Everything seems to be valid and in order but when I run in utop I get a type error described below

```
let rec get_src src alist = match alist with
  |[]-> failwith "no source"
  |(r,c,d)::t -> if c = src then (r,c,d) else get_src src t

let move_column (src:int) (dst:int) alist =
  let src_elt = get_src src alist in
  let rec move_helper src dst alist new_list = match alist with
    |[] -> new_list
    |(r,c,data)::tail ->
       if (dst < 1 || src < 1) then failwith ("index out of range")
       else if (src < dst) then
         (if ((c < src) || (c > dst)) then move_helper src dst tail ((r,c,data)::new_list)
          else if (c = src) then move_helper src dst tail new_list
          else if (c = dst) then move_helper src dst tail ((r,c-1,data)::src_elt::new_list)
          else move_helper src dst tail ((r,c-1,data)::new_list))
       else if (src > dst) then
         (if (c < dst) || (c > src) then move_helper src dst tail ((r,c,data)::new_list)
          else if (c = dst) then move_helper src dst tail (src_elt::new_list)
          else move_helper src dst tail ((r,c+1,data)::new_list))
  in move_helper src dst alist [];;
```

if (c < dst) || (c > src) then ***move_helper src dst tail ((r,c,data)::new_list)***

**Error**: This expression has type ('a * int * 'b) list
       but an expression was expected of type unit

I am not sure where I put new_list's type as the unit type. May it have to do with my get_src function?

Comment: You're missing an `else` branch on the outermost `if` expression. The compiler doesn't run the predicate expressions, and therefore does not know  they cover all the cases with a catch-all `else` branch, hence it will always assume that an if-expression without `else` has a type of `unit`

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (src > dst)` has only a `then` part, but no `else` part. OCaml allows this, but it supplies the value `()` for the else part. In other words, it requires the `then` part to have type `unit`. That's what is causing the type error.

You need to decide what to return when `src = dst` and then write the `else` part for `if (src > dst)`.